# Can logistic regression be used with "years" as a continuous variable?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, categorical-data

We are currently collecting data for a study whose purpose is to show whether scientists are focusing more or less on a specific subject with time. To keep some privacy let's say the subject is *jelly beans*: we reviewed a thousand random studies and we checked whether they were about jelly beans or not. The dataset has only two columns and it looks like:

```
| JellyBeans | Year |
|------------|------|
|    YES     | 2010 |
|    NO      | 2001 |
|    NO      | 2010 |
|    NO      | 2015 |
|    YES     | 2009 |
|    NO      | 2016 |
|    ...     | .... |
|    YES     | 1999 |
```

We thought of using logistic regression for the purpose as the DV is categorical. In R, this would look something like:

```
logreg_jelly_year = glm(JellyBeans ~ Year, family = "binomial", data = dataset)
```

We have, however, some doubts about the validity of the procedure, in particular:

1. Is there any specific assumption we have to check that could jeopardise the scientific value of the procedure?
2. Is the fact that `Year` is not truly continuous a problem?
3. Is there any other test or procedure that we should run on top or instead of logistic regression?

Comment: See also http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65900/does-it-make-sense-to-use-a-date-variable-in-a-regression Any kind of model seems overkill here to me: why not just plot the observed proportions against time?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use years as a continuous variable in your model. But, I would not be estimating a logit model for this problem. Some specific issues:

- The way to show your data here is as a plot, where the x-axis shows the years, and the y-axis shows the proportion of jelly beans. Estimating a logit model to do this brings with it the risk that you make an error, but no benefits of any kind in terms of interpretation.
- If you are desperate to compute a *p*-value, you would be better off using Kendall's tau-b, as then you have no assumptions to worry about.
- If the plot reveals a non-linear relationship I suppose you could use a logit model with a polynomial effect, using, say, `JellyBeans ~ poly(Year, 3)` or something similar and a likelihood ratio test for significance of the model.

Comment: I'd try a logistic GAM instead of a polynomial.

Comment: Better to use [tag:splines] instead of polynomials. Polynomials are unstable at the extremes, and the later years may be exactly what we are most interested in. And once you use splines, a logistic model *does* give you more information than a simple Kendall's correlation.

Comment: I saw I do not remember where that it could be useful to add/subtract a constant value to the _year_ variable in order to treat it as continuous. GAM as well might be an option.

Comment: @Moazzem Hossen: subtracting the mean of the Year can be useful in terms of avoiding computational error. But, the simplicity of this problem means it will not be necessary.

Comment: @Roland I agree a spline is a better solution. But, it is also a lot harder to implement if the asked is not so familiar with the area.

Comment: @Tim, regarding your first point, would you run a simple linear regression between years and proportion to jelly beans? That would simplify my life AND give me a so-desired p-value.

Comment: @Secret Parrot, a regression is going to be just as useful as a logit model. But, a plot and a nonparametric test is still the better approach in my opinion.