# Is dummy coding required when spacing is meaningful (number of days)?

Tags: regression, ordered-logit, categorical-encoding

I apologise if this has been asked before. If so, please point me the right way. However, I have had a look and cannot find an appropriate answer.

I am attempting to fit cumulative logit models using the Ordinal (clm) and VGAM (vglm) R packages. I have continuous and discrete explanatory variables. Both discrete variables are the number of days it rained in a month, so take a single integer value between 0-31. As the distances between each value are equal regardless of level (0|1 = 15|16 = 30|31) are dummy variables required?

If so, I understand some R regression packages automatically dummy code factors, is this the case with the clm and vglm packages?

Finally, how would you recommend selecting the reference variable for these dummy variables?

Comment: Here is a similiar question asking about the use of dates in a regression model
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65900/does-it-make-sense-to-use-a-date-variable-in-a-regression

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does it make sense to use a date variable in a regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65900/does-it-make-sense-to-use-a-date-variable-in-a-regression)

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate of that one as the OP here has number of days, not a date strictly speaking @MattL.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332688/what-type-of-data-are-dates/332715#332715

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are prepared to assume that scientifically the difference between 1 day and 2 days is the same as between 20 days and 21 days then you could enter this as continuous either as a linear term or something more complicated.

Since it is a continuous variable there is no reference category strictly speaking although the intercept in your model will be estimated for your covariates all having the value zero.

Comment: I ended up standardising frequency measure, producing a proportion of days it rained per month. However, I did still have an option to use continuous or categorical with month.

I am including month in the model to try to explain any seasonal effects that are not explained by the other covariates. As this is unlikely to be linear I have dummy coded it. However, if other effects demonstrate a non-linear effect I'll likely run a nonparametric ordinal regression model. 

Thank you for your help!